# Show that $x^2+9x+20$ is divisible by 2 for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, quadratics, factoring

I'm having extremely hard time getting how proof by induction should work for this case.

This is my attempt so far:

(1) When $x = 1$

$1^2 + 9 + 20 = 30$ which is divisible by 2.

(2) Now assume that it is true when $x = k$

$k^2 + 9k + 20$ is divisible by 2

(3) Then $x = k + 1$

$(k + 1)^2 + 9(k + 1) + 20 = k^2 + 2k + 1 + 9k + 9 + 20 = k^2 + 11k + 30$

And now I'm stuck. I could continue it with $k(k + 11) + 30$ but I don't understand how would that bring me closer to the solution. Maybe my approach is wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What's the difference with $k^2+9k+20$?

Comment: $k^2 + 11k + 30=(k^2 + 9k + 20)+(2k+10)$

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to do the case of $x=0$ and do "reverse" induction (go from $0$ to $-1$ to $-2$, ...).

Comment: I think more people should upvote this question because the user has shown some effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$x^2+9x+20$$
We can factorise this to $$(x+4)(x+5)$$
Take $r=x+4$. We now have $$r(r+1)$$For some integer input $x$, and as a result, a integer input $r$, we have an expression for the product of two consecutive integers. One of these *must* be odd and the other *must* be even.  We know that an even integer multiplied by an odd integer must be even, and so the output of your expression must be even too.

Comment: Everyone was a huge help, but the line $r = x + 4$ helped me finally get it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Because  $$x^2+9x+20=(x+4)(x+5).$$

Answer (score 4):

Write the given expression as $x^2+x+8x+20$; the last two terms are individually even always.

The first two terms can be written as $x(x+1)$, a product of two consecutive integers. One of them is always even so the product too is even.

Comment: Could you please explain why one of them is always even?

Comment: Be $2a$ an even number while $2a+1$ is its consecutive, then: $2a(2a+1)=2b$ (for $b=a(2a+1)$) is an even number.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$\begin{align}
\text{odd}\times \text{odd}&=\text{odd}, \\
\text{odd}\times \text{even}&=\text{even}, \quad \text{and}\\
\text{even}\times \text{even}&=\text{even}
\end{align}$$ and

$$\begin{align}
\text{odd}+ \text{odd}&=\text{even}, \\
\text{odd}+ \text{even}&=\text{odd}, \quad \text{and}\\
\text{even}+ \text{even}&=\text{even}.
\end{align}$$

Thus we have, when $x$ is odd, that

$$\begin{align}
x^2+9x+20&=\text{odd}^2+\text{odd}(\text{odd})+\text{even} \\
&=\text{odd}+\text{odd}+\text{even}\\
&=\text{even}+\text{even}\\
&=\text{even}.
\end{align}$$

This is equivalent to using modular arithmetic.

Can you do the case when $x$ is even?

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $(k+1)^2+9(k+1)+20$ is divisible by $2$ given that $k^2+9k+20$ is divisible by $2$.

$[(k+1)^2+9(k+1)+20]-(k^2+9k+20)=(2k+1)+9=2(k+5)$ which is divisible by $2$.

Hence $[(k+1)^2+9(k+1)+20]$ is divisible by $2$.

Also, as mentioned by Cameron, we have to consider non-positive numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^2+9x+20 = (x+4)(x+5)
$$

so for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an even number.

Answer (score 1):

**First method:**

$x=2k\Rightarrow x^2+9x+20=4k^2+18k+20=2(2k^2+9k+10)$

while

$x=2k+1\Rightarrow 
\color{red}{x^2}+\color{green}{9x}+\color{blue}{20}=
\color{red}{4k^2+4k+1}+\color{green}{18k+9}+\color{blue}{20}=
2(2k^2+11k+15)$

**Second method (by induction):**

Let $p(x)=x^2+9x+20$ and let $P(x)$ be $2\vert p(x) \forall x\in\mathbb Z$, to be proved.

Then $p(0)=20$ and $p(1)=30$ so $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ are true.

Suppose $P(x)$ is true for some $x>0$, this is $2\vert p(x)$. Then $2\vert p(x+1)$ if and only if $2\vert p(x+1)-p(x)$.

$p(x+1)-p(x)=(x+1)^2+9(x+1)+20-(x^2+9x+20)=2(x+5)$

so $2\vert p(x+1)-p(x)$ and $P(x+1)$ is also true.

By the way, $2\vert p(x)-p(-x)=18x$ so $P(x)$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb Z^-\cup \left\{0\right\}\cup\mathbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 0):

For fun;

$x(x+9)+20 =$

$(x+10-10)(x+9) +20=$

$(x+10)(x+9) -10(x+9) +20$.

1) $2$ divides $(x+10)(x+9)$ (Why?)

2) $2$ divides $(-10(x+9))$ (Why?)

3) $2$ divides $20$ ,

hence $2$ divides the sum of the above terms.